# Как обработать в одном обработчике 2 события released() и pressed()?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть кнопка(QPushButton), при нажатии выставляется одна картинка, при отпускании кнопки мыши картинка меняется на первоначальную. Хочется сделать в одном обработчике. Т.е на псевдокоде:

```
connect(PushButton, SIGNAL(Какой-то сигнал),this,SLOT(buttonHandler()))

buttonHandler(){
if event.pressed() 
       button->setImage(1)
else
       button->setImage(2)
 }
```

Как правильно реализовывать такое поведение в Qt? Неужели пихать 2 обработчика для 2-х событий(released и pressed) и делать 2 connect-а ?

Comment: сигнал clicked не устаивает?

Comment: @Данил clicked испускается когда пользователь нажал и отпустил мышку. Мне же на зажатой надо устанавливать одну картинку при отпускании - другую.

Comment: У вас два разных действия на два разных события, значит надо делать два соединения

Comment: @BeardedBeaver А нет ли какой-то возможности сделать кастомное событие, которое имеет общие свойства с pressed и  released ?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Либо считать сигнал в одном обработчике ?

Comment: Теоретически можно переопределить `event` и внутри проверить тип события, но на практике я этого никогда не делал, надо разбираться. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event

Answer (score 1):

Ну в итоге лучше решения не нашел, кроме как 2 события прикрутить к одному обработчику след образом. Если есть решение более элегантное, то прошу рассказать))

```
void MainWindow::changeAddDictionaryIcon(){
    QPushButton* sender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());
    if (sender->isDown()){
        addDictionaryPushButton->setIcon(QIcon("Path to img1"));
    }else{
        addDictionaryPushButton->setIcon(QIcon("Path to img2"));
    }
}
```